# How to use jquery without $?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

When is jquery like this, it works:

```
 if( jQuery('.cmp .input-rangeslider-' + inputName).hasClass('do-not-update') ){
        jQuery('.cmp .input-rangeslider-' + inputName).removeClass('do-not-update');   
    }
```

But when i write jquery like this:

```
if(jQuery('.cmp .nemovitosti input[name="type"]:checked')){
$(".answer").show();
}
    else{
    $(".answer").hide();
}
```

it cause this error: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Wordpress the `$` variable does not refer to jQuery (by default). To work around this you need to alias it yourself in the document.ready event handler.

Also note that your `if` statement in the second code example is flawed, as a jQuery object always equates to `true`. You need to move the `:checked` selector to a separate call to `is()`, which will return a boolean:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  if ($('.cmp .nemovitosti input[name="type"]').is(':checked')) {
    $(".answer").show();
  } else {
    $(".answer").hide();
  }
});
```

Finally, this logic can be reduced further by providing the boolean value from `is()` to the `toggle()` function, which will display or hide the target element.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $(".answer").toggle($('.cmp .nemovitosti input[name="type"]').is(':checked'));
});
```